# Tkinter grid() not allinging as supposed to

Tags: python, tkinter

everyone!
I am a new python learner and I'm trying to use Tkinter to create a GUI window.

So far I have the following code to configure the UI setup:

```
from tkinter import *
# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #

# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #

# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=40, pady=40)

##### Creating logo image
canvas=Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_image = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

##### Creating labels
website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

username_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
username_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

password_label = Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

##### Creating buttons
add_button = Button(text='Add', width=36)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

generate_button = Button(text='Generate Password')
generate_button.grid(row=3, column=2)

##### Creating entries
website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
website_entry.focus()

username_entry = Entry(width=35)
username_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
username_entry.insert(0, "dummy_email@hotmail.com")

password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

But when I run this code, the tkinter window is as follow:

[Tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKdD7.png)

It was supposed to align the generate password button with add button and website/email entry.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I will suggest to add `sticky="w"` to `grid(...)` for labels, `sticky="ew"` for entries and buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `sticky` to *stick* it to to `e` *east* or `w` *west*. In addition I have used the same column for the password button and adjustet the width of the entry`s.

```
from tkinter import *
# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #

# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #

# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=40, pady=40)

##### Creating logo image
canvas=Canvas(width=200, height=200)
#logo_image = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
#canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

##### Creating labels
website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky='w')

username_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
username_label.grid(row=2, column=0,sticky='w')

password_label = Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0,sticky='w')

##### Creating buttons
add_button = Button(text='Add', width=36)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='w')

generate_button = Button(text='Generate Password')
generate_button.grid(row=3, column=1,sticky='e')

##### Creating entries
website_entry = Entry(width=43)
website_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2,sticky='w')
website_entry.focus()

username_entry = Entry(width=43)
username_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2,sticky='w')
username_entry.insert(0, "dummy_email@hotmail.com")

password_entry = Entry(width=24)
password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1,sticky='w')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With a little tweak with "sticky" attribute and adding columnspan to the image, I got everything aligned as planned!

Answer (score 0):

One way to align the buttons would be to set the `sticky` argument to `E` when placing the `Add` button on the grid.

You could also use `sticky` to line up the other widgets as required.

```py
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=E)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With a little tweak with "sticky" attribute and adding columnspan to the image, I got everything aligned as planned!